# How can I disable program notifications and popups in bottom right corner?

Tags: windows-7, notifications, popups

I have an older computer running Windows 7 SP1. I find that some installed programs, like antivirus trial, Flux, etc. decide they want to present some info to me in the form of a smaller screen with an X close button. Typically these are in the bottom right corner of the screen, above status tray.

I find that these popups frequently interrupt full screen movies or games and **I want to totally silence apps running in the tray or background** and prevent from from creating any windows unless I explicitly open the app.

**How can I make sure an app running in the system tray cannot create popup windows?**
[image]

I have already fiddled with Windows settings and disabled "balloon notifications" and notifications explicitly labeled as promotional, but that did not solve the problem.

Comment: Part of the answer turns into "what app?"  For applications that use the Windows notification event hooks and "play by the rules" it is fairly easy to adjust their notification performance, as 7h2w1z4rd shows.  But if the app developer decided "screw it, I'll make a notification bubble control myself" then those settings (if they even exist) will be within that app somewhere.  I mention this because the screen shot shows a notification using a style that doesn't look like standard Win 7 notifications, and could be a "screw it, we made a custom one."

Comment: You need to crack it look into Shell_NotifyIconA function (shell32) is the reaponsable for showing that notification before the call catch it and cancel it use ollydbg or similiar